# The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int

Tags: java, arrays

I have a code but it shows the error The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[],   int

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String [] args) {  
    int[] n = {2,3,5,7};
    System.out.println(arePrimeFactors(n));      
    }
    public static boolean arePrimeFactors(int[] n){
            boolean a = arePrimeFactors(n); 
                        if (n%2==0) {
                            return false;
               for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
                        if(n%i==0)
                            return false;
        }
               return true;
            }}}
```

can you guys pls check I'm new to java 
thanks

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two very different languages

Comment: Given that `n` is array, what do you expect `n%2` to be?

Comment: n is an array not an int, plus your first line of the arePrimeFactors method causes an infinite recursive loop. even if it compiled it wouldn't run correctly

Comment: Also, the first line of `arePrimeFactors(int[] n)` calls `arePrimeFactors(n);`  If you get the syntax errors fixed, you're going to have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because `n` is an array, you need to specify which element you are using your modulus operator on:

```
if (n[index] % 2 == 0) {
    //So stuff...
}
```

An array can contain multiple values at multiple indices, for example: `n` can range anywhere from `{1, 6, 4, 2, 8}` to `{10245, 23451, 35312, 1}`. You need to pass an index number into the brackets to specify which element you are using

Consider this:  If you had an array `int[] i = {1, 2, 3, 4};`and you wanted to reference the `2`, than you would type `i[1]`. This is because in Java indexing starts at zero rather then one, so for the second element you would pass a `1` rather than a `2`. This picture gives you an idea of what I mean:

[image]